# Using the Jenkins Java API in a Workflow Script

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I'm trying to take advantage of the Jenkins Java from within a Workflow groovy script.

I'm finding it very difficult to get to grips with what I can and can't do, are there any good resources on how to do this.

At the moment what I'm trying to do is get the workspace path, I've got as far as

```
def jenkins = Jenkins.instance;
def build = jenkins.getItem(env.JOB_NAME).getBuild(env.BUILD_NUMBER)
```

But this seems to be a dead end, there doesn't seem to be anything useful you can actually do with these objects.

If anyone can point me at any resources giving examples of the kind of useful things that can be done like this, or help with my specific problem of getting the workspace path that would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the standard Workflow step `pwd()` to get the workspace path, without any use of Jenkins APIs.

As far as other cases are concerned, there is no particular document summarizing what you can do with Jenkins APIs from a Workflow script, because it is simply whatever the Jenkins APIs allow you to do generally (see [Javadoc](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/)). Two caveats you need to be aware of:

- Almost all such calls will be rejected by the Groovy sandbox (and many are not safe to whitelist). This means that you cannot write such scripts in a secured Jenkins installation unless you are an administrator. [more](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Script+Security+Plugin)
- Most API objects will not be `Serializable`, which means that you must encapsulate their use in a method marked with the `@NonCPS` annotation. The method may take as parameters and return any serializable (or primitive) types. [more](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#serializing-local-variables)
- Currently there is no supported way to get access to Jenkins model objects which are defined in a local workspace context. [JENKINS-28385](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28385) would help. In the meantime, there are often workarounds; for example, if you want the `Node` you are using inside a `node {}` block, you can use `Jenkins.instance.getNode(env.NODE_NAME)`.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your overarching question, but env.WORKSPACE will give you the absolute path to the workspace :)  Open the Snippet Generator in a Workflow job config, scroll down, and you will see a list of all the available environment variables.

Comment: env.WORKSPACE is giving me null and it does say in the snippet generator that it isn't supported.

Comment: For this particular case, you can simply use the `pwd()` step.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the workspace path for the purpose of reading some files, you should really be using a Job DSL and `readFileFromWorkspace(filePath)`. 
Just having a workspace path and trying to read file with `new File(filePath)` may not work if you are using slaves. 
More details are here 
https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Job-DSL-Commands